# How can we save the varition of a configurable product dynamically

Tags: magento2, addtocart

**How can we save the variation of a configurable product dynamically ? Please Help me.**

```
protected $_cart;
protected $productRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
)
{
    $this->_cart = $cart;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

...
...

$productId = 10; // enter your product_id
$qty = 1; // enter number of quantites you want to add

/*
I am using the below ids as configurable options for example purposes only.
You have to use your attribute id and option id.

90 = attribute_id of color 
53 = option_id of any specific color,

143 = attribute_id of size
170 = option_id of any specific size
*/

$options = array(
                90 => 53,
                143 => 170
            );

$params = array(
    'product' => $productId,
    'super_attribute' => $options,
    'qty' => $qty
);

$_product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
$this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
$this->_cart->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code.

Send below the object to add the product.

```
$objParam = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        [
            'product' => $product->getId(), //configurable product id
            'selected_configurable_option' => $childid, //selected simple product id
            'qty' => $item['qty'],
            'super_attribute' => $attributes
        ]
    );
```

update our code as per your requirement.

```
   //create configurable product order
if ($productType == 'configurable') {
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
        ->addFilter('order_id', $orderId)
        ->addFilter('parent_item_id', $item['order_item_id'])
        ->create();

    $ordersItemList = $this->orderItemRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

    foreach ($ordersItemList as $itemchild) {
        $childid = $itemchild->getProductId();
        $ItemId = $itemchild->getItemId();
        if ($itemchild->getProductType() == 'simple') {
            $attributes = $itemchild->getProductOptions()['info_buyRequest']['super_attribute'];
        }
    }
    $objParam = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        [
            'product' => $product->getId(), //configurable product id
            'selected_configurable_option' => $childid, //selected simple product id
            'qty' => $item['qty'],
            'super_attribute' => $attributes
        ]
    );
}

$this->cart->addProduct($product, $objParam);
$this->_cart->save();
```

Comment: bro i want to save the values in cart not in order can you advise me according the product cart Thanks

Comment: above code is only used for products save into the cart

Comment: $objParam = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        [
            'product' => $product->getId(), //configurable product id
            'selected_configurable_option' => $childid, //selected simple product id
            'qty' => $item['qty'],
            'super_attribute' => $attributes
        ]
    );

Comment: Send above the object to add the product into cart.

Answer (score 0):

**here is my code which i am using can you edit for configurable**

```
<?php
```

namespace Greenplank\Addtocart\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
 */
protected $cart;
protected $product;
protected $resultFactory;
protected $productRepository;
protected $formKey;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
    // \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productFactory,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
) {
    $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->product = $product;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    // $this->productFactory = $_productFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
      // if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
      //       return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
      //   }
    
    try {
        $params = array();
        // $params['qty'] = '1';//product quantity
        $skuId =$_GET['sku'];
        $_product = $this->productRepository->get($skuId);
        $qty= $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty');
        // $options = array(
        //     93 => 992,
        //     194 => 984
        // );
        $params=array(
           'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
           // 'super_attribute' => $options, 
           'qty'=> $qty 
        );
        // $options = [];
        // $productAttributeOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
        // foreach($productAttributeOptions as $option){
        //     $options[$option['attribute_id']] =  $childProduct->getData($option['attribute_code']);
        // }
        // $params['super_attribute'] = $options;
        if ($_product){
            $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
            $this->cart->save();
        }
        // /*cart page*/
        //  $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        // // Your code
        // $resultRedirect->setUrl("/checkout/cart");
        // return $resultRedirect;

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Lägg i kundvagnen framgångsrikt.'));
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addException(
            $e,
            __('%1', $e->getMessage())
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('error.'));
   }
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect('/checkout/cart/');       
 }
```

}